# Refresh the display of an activity when it is visible again

Tags: android, refresh

I have two activities (`TextActivity.java` and `GrammarActivity.java`), on which one fragment (`ChoixLangue.java`) is a radio group with four buttons to select a language of translation.
The parent of `GrammarActivity` is `TextActivity`.
I can select the language I want either on `TextActivity` or `GrammarActivity`. And I can change it on whichever ativity I am as well.
But if I select a language on `TextActivity`, then go to `GrammarActivity` and change the language, and then **kill** `GrammarActivity`, which takes me back to `TextActivity`, it displays the wrong radio button checked - presumably because the display of `TextActivity` is not **refreshed**.
How to fix this bug? Here is a part of the code in TextActivity `

```
public class TextActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public ImageButton monImageBouton;
public Button monBouton;
public TextView monTextView;
public static RadioButton monBoutonRadio;
public static String langueChoisie = "francais";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_text);

    // une des solutions pour rendre la zone trado scrollable
    TextView myXmlContent = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.zone_trado_scrollable);
    myXmlContent.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

    verifLangue();
    playText();
    test("button8"); // indique la langue choisie
}


public void verifLangue(){
    if(langueChoisie == "english"){
        monBoutonRadio = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.english);
        monBoutonRadio.setChecked(true);
    }
    else if(langueChoisie == "espanol"){
        monBoutonRadio = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.espanol);
        monBoutonRadio.setChecked(true);
    }
    else if(langueChoisie == "chinois"){
        monBoutonRadio = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.chinois);
        monBoutonRadio.setChecked(true);
    }
    else{
        monBoutonRadio = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.francais);
        monBoutonRadio.setChecked(true);
    }
}

public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {

    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.english:
            if (checked)
                langueChoisie = "english";
            break;
        case R.id.francais:
            if (checked)
                langueChoisie = "francais"; // checked et définie a priori
            break;
        case R.id.espanol:
            if (checked)
                langueChoisie = "espanol";
            break;
        case R.id.chinois:
            if (checked)
                langueChoisie = "chinois";
            break;
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm fully understood your question but the best choice would be to use eventhandlers for radio buttons which will get the selected value and store it for both classes (Grammer and Text).
(I'm assuming you want the choice you made for Grammer activity should be kept for Text activity as well.)

Comment: Actually, the value of the language chosen is correctly recorded and shared by the two activities. It is just the "display" of the chosen language, when I go back to TextActivity, which is not updated (but the translations do function with the new language chosen).

Comment: do you have any ItemListeners then? a code snippet would be nice

Comment: you can edit your question or write the code in between ` code` tag